# How to attach a workflow to a list, and how to email the assigned person?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, custom

I am quite new with Sharepoint so please forgive me any errors in my understanding of how it works.

I need to create a Sharepoint site that coordinates the creation of various reports across divisions which are eventually aggregated and present to the client. Also I am using the Office 2010 suite.

My plan initially was to create a custom list with the columns, among others:

> Consultant, LDI Assigned To, EDOS Assigned To, Governance Writer and
>   Governance Checker

When client services create a new entry in the list and type in the reporting deadlines for this client, they select the above people, and, as it starts, I want them to get a email.

After a lot of searching, I have read that a way to do this, is something like this:

```
    Step 1 
    Wait for Consultant to be not empty
    Step 2
    if Current Item:Consultant is not empty
    Email %Current Item:Consultant%
```

However, despite having created this workflow by clicking on 'New' from within the Workflows box on the list settings management page within Sharepoint Designer, when I complete it and go back to the list settings page, nothing is listed.

Indeed, on the Workflow settings page under 'Task List:' the correct list is not an option.

I then tried creating a list from the Task List template and creating the same workflow, this, eventually seemed to stick. But it doesn't send the email as it should, and the default template contains many columns I don't want. One named 'Type' in particular I have no idea of the purpose of, and I can't remove it.

How can I attach a workflow to a custom list, and what is wrong with my email code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really new in the SharePoint world, you should probably use a search engine of your choice and type in something like:

> first sharepoint designer workflow

That should help you how to attach a workflow to your list.